# Java Object in Android Studio Which is Constructed by Call to Rest API

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-volley

I am writing an app in Android Studio which notifies the user of train times. I have a class called Journey and my idea (not sure if this is the right way to go about it as I am new to Java and Android development) is to set the attributes based on the returned response from the API. The call to the API is working and I am able to set the attributes, but how can I make it so that the calling class will listen until it has finished the call to the API and fully loaded the attributes.

The code I have at the moment is as below:

```
public Journey(String startCode, String endCode, Activity activity) {
    //Connect to the API and set up the journey object

updateJourney(startCode,endCode,activity);


}


public void updateJourney(String startCode, final String endCode, Activity activity) {
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
    final Journey journeyClass = this;

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,URL_LEFT + URL_START + startCode + URL_DEST + endCode,null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d("Response", response.toString());

                if (response.length() != 0) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject returnedJourney = response.getJSONObject(0);
                        journeyClass.setStartCode(returnedJourney.getString("station"));
                        journeyClass.setEndCode(endCode);

                        JSONArray services = returnedJourney.getJSONArray("services");
                        JSONObject firstService = services.getJSONObject(0);
                        journeyClass.setDepartTime(firstService.getString("depfriendly"));
                        journeyClass.setArriveTime(firstService.getString("arrfriendly"));
                        journeyClass.setStatus(firstService.getString("schedule_status"));

                        Log.d("journey arrival",journeyClass.getArriveTime());

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    //Returned response is empty - deal wth
                }
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO: Handle error
                //Log.d("URL", URL_LEFT + URL_START + startCode + URL_DEST + endCode);
                VolleyLog.d("error", error.getMessage());
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}
```

There probably is a set way of going about this whole thing, but like I said I am very new to this. I have searched online, but not quite sure exactly how you do this in Java. I'm not sure if setting an instance of the class is right, but that's what I thought of as a way of setting the attributes from within the inner class.

UPDATE:

I am using the below within the listener which seems like it might be working. I will need to tidy up all the code and will get back later if this works as the solution. I have to go to work now for the next 8 hours.

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView station = getActivity().findViewById(stationFieldId);
        station.setText(stationName);
        TextView timeField = getActivity().findViewById(timeFieldId);
        timeField.setText(journey.getDepartTime());
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure If I got it correctly, do you want the caller class to get notified once the response is either get succeeded or failed? kindly clarify

Comment: From my understanding the call to the API happens Asynchronously so in the fragment class which calls the constructor it fails if you run Log.d("journey arrival",journey.getArriveTime()); after calling the constructor. My assumption of what is happening there, is that it hasn't finished the API call yet as the object is being constructed the response listener class.

Comment: I tried moving the API call to the calling class, but I run into the same issue. If I try to update a TextView from within the listener then I get a null object exception. I can't find anything online which explains how to do this clearly. Can someone help?

Comment: You write network logic for requesting something in other class and you use listener to pass the data back to target, Draw a diagram what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure how to draw a diagram of it, but basically I need to execute a call to an API and then update a TextView within the UI with data retrieved from the API.

Comment: paste your complete code including from which class you are calling

Comment: Hi notTdar, I think, I am getting it working now using the runOnUiThread method. I will post an update and the full code once I have tidied it up and got it working.

Comment: hold on, did you try to access ui elements from background thread? if that's the case, then ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220339/discussion-between-nottdar-and-rlbchrisbriant).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used in the end which worked for me. I have edited out a lot of the stuff it is doing with the UI elements to include the part where it is setting the TextViews

```
private void getJourneyAndDisplay(String startCode, final String destCode, final String stationName, final int stationFieldId, final int timeFieldId, final int statusFieldId, final boolean out) {
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    journey = new Journey();

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Journey.URL_LEFT + Journey.URL_START + startCode + Journey.URL_DEST + destCode, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    if (response.length() != 0) {
                        try {
                            //Make panel visible as it has returned results
                            panel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            JSONArray services = returnedJourney.getJSONArray("services");
                            if (services.length() > 0) {
                     //Journey object is configured

                                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Activity act = getActivity();
                                        TextView station = act.findViewById(stationFieldId);
                                        station.setText(stationName);
                                        TextView timeField = act.findViewById(timeFieldId);
                                        timeField.setText(journey.getDepartTime());
                                        TextView statusField = act.findViewById(statusFieldId);
                                        statusField.setText(journey.getStatus());
                                    }
                                });

                            } else {
                 //Deal iwth no joruney
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            //Display message to inform user that the data cannot be retrieved
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Returned response is empty
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //Handle reponse
                }
            });
    queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```